# each_element not behaving as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rexml

When I'm in irb and I do something like this:

```
node_list.each_element { |e| puts e.text }
```

It works and prints one line of text per element returned (plus I think it returns the xml object).  However, when I head over to rails and have things moving between controllers, helpers, views and layouts it just dumps the xml object.

I should mention that for good reasons I'm using rails 1.2.3 and ruby 1.8.7.

Gratzi!

Comment: what does your view look like, I think I know the problem your having

Comment: hmm. maybe this is the important line: <%= tol_get_names(@child1) %> where tol_get_names is just a function that does what i wrote above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue your having is that puts writes to console and not the template.  Also, in ruby the a method will return by default its last object.  So your method as written will loop through @child1, print each's text to the console, and then return the @child1 object at which point your erb tags of <%= %> tells it print the object (@child1 in this case)

You have two options, either you can move it out into the template:

```
<% tol_get_names(@child1) do |e| %> #note just <% and not <%=
  <%= e.text %>
<% end %>
```

Or build your method so that it loops through building a string and then returns that string instead of the original object:

```
def tol_get_names(child)
  texts = [] #empty array for all our values
  child.each_element { |e| 
    texts << e.text #add the text string to our array
  end
  texts.join(", ") #build a string and seperate it with a comma
end
```

Several ways you could write this type of method, but this is my usual way.